# How can I configure my server to not suppress errors?

Tags: php, plesk

I'm running a server via plesk panel, and I'm having problems with it not displaying errors it is encountering. Instead, it is just spitting back server error. I eventually work my way around the problem and figure out what exists, but I'm hoping to get some help configuring my server to spit out debug.

Comment: Take a look at the FAQ section [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/infohttp://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info), you will need to scroll down a bit.

Comment: @vascowhite the link you have provided is "Page Not Found"

Comment: better than server error!

Comment: Don't know what happened there. @user2605381, here is the link. http://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info

Answer (score 0):

As you said you are using Plesk panel, Pleask panel will provide options to customize php configurations for each and every domain and subdomains.

Follow this links after logging into the Plesk Panel

Home --> Domains --> Manage Domain --> Websites and Domains --> Domain Name --> php settings

OR Follow as below
GO TO
Home --> Domains

In the list of the domain shown, find the domain to which php configuration has to change and click on the link "Open in Control Panel" associated to that domain.

Now you will be in the "Websites and Domains" page and here you will find all the list of Websites and Domains available in the server.

on clicking the domain name you will be redirected to the page where you will find a "php settings" link.

Click the php settings link and you will find some of the php configuration settings available to that domain. Change these settings as desired.

Answer (score 0):

There is also option to suppress php errors through .htaccess

Use the below lines in the .htaccess file to not displaying errors (php)

php_flag display_errors off
php_value error_reporting 0